# Java - Index a String (Substring)

Tags: indexing, substring, cut

I have this string:

> 201057&channelTitle=null_JS

I want to be able to cut out the '201057' and make it a new variable. But I don't always know how long the digits will be, so can I somehow use the '&' as a reference?\

myDigits substring(0, position of &)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can split the string along the &.

```
String s = "201057&channelTitle=null_JS";
String[] parts = s.split("&");
String newVar = parts[0];
```

The expected result here is

```
parts[0] = "201057";
parts[1] = "channelTitle=null_JS";
```

In production code you chould check of course the length of the parts array, in case no "&" was present.

Several programming languages also support the useful inverse operation

```
String s2 = parts.join("&");  // should have same value like s
```

Alas this one is not part of the Java standard libs, but e.g. Apache Commons Lang features it.

Answer (score 0):

Always read the API first. There is an indexOf method in String that will return you the first index of the character/String you gave it.

You can use myDigits.substring(0, myDigits.indexOf('&');

However, if you want to get all of the arguments in the query separately, then you should use mvw's answer.